# Use same CFBundleVersion and CFBundleShortVersionString in all targets

Tags: ios, xcode, version

I received the following email from Apple when I submit an app update:

> We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for
>   "Project". Your delivery was successful, but you may
>   wish to correct the following issues in your next delivery:
>
> **CFBundleVersion Mismatch** - The CFBundleVersion value '1' of extension
>   'Project.app/PlugIns/ProjectTodayExtension.appex' does not
>   match the CFBundleVersion value '985' of its containing iOS
>   application 'Project.app'.
>
> **CFBundleShortVersionString Mismatch** - The CFBundleShortVersionString
>   value '1.0' of extension 'Project.app/PlugIns/ProjectTodayExtension.appex' does not
>   match the CFBundleShortVersionString value '2.1.6' of its containing
>   iOS application 'Project.app'.
>
> After you’ve corrected the issues, you can use Xcode or Application
>   Loader to upload a new binary to iTunes Connect.

Is there any way of use the same **CFBundleVersion** and **CFBundleShortVersionString** in all targets to prevent this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

My solution is:

For **CFBundleShortVersionString**:

- Add a user-defined constant in your **project** settings

[image: Add a user-defined constant in your **project** settings]

- Name it **$(CF_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING)** and set it to your desired value

[image]

- Set your version in your targets to **$(CF_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING)**

[image]

- Repeat for all targets. **Done**!

---

**CFBundleVersion**: you could do the same for **CFBundleVersion**, but somehow I wanted this value to be computed from my GIT repo commit count. I´ve done it like this:

- Add a Pre-action to your **main target**. You access the shown dialog via **Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme**

[image]

- Add a Post-action to your **main target**.

[image]

- Add a new Command Line Tool target named **BundleVersionUpdate** and one named **BundleVersionRevert**

[image]

- Navigate to your new **BundleVersionUpdate** target and add a new Run Script Build Phase

[image]

- Paste the following

> ```
> \#!/bin/sh
>
> INFOPLIST="${SRCROOT}/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist"
> INFOPLIST_WKAPP="${SRCROOT}/MyApp-WKApp/Info.plist"
> INFOPLIST_WKEXT="${SRCROOT}/MyApp-WKExt/Info.plist"
>
> PLISTCMD="Set :CFBundleVersion $(git rev-list --all|wc -l)"
>
> echo -n "$INFOPLIST" 
> | xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$PLISTCMD"
>
> echo -n "$INFOPLIST_WKAPP" 
> | xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$PLISTCMD"
>
> echo -n "$INFOPLIST_WKEXT" 
> | xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$PLISTCMD"
> ```

- Navigate to your new **BundleVersionRevert** target and add a new Run Script Build Phase and paste this:

> ```
> \#!/bin/sh
>
> INFOPLIST="${SRCROOT}/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist"
> INFOPLIST_WKAPP="${SRCROOT}/MyApp-WKApp/Info.plist"
> INFOPLIST_WKEXT="${SRCROOT}/MyApp-WKExt/Info.plist"
>
> PLISTCMD="Set :CFBundleVersion SCRIPTED"
>
> echo -n "$INFOPLIST" 
> | xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$PLISTCMD"
>
> echo -n "$INFOPLIST_WKAPP" 
> | xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$PLISTCMD"
>
> echo -n "$INFOPLIST_WKEXT" 
> | xargs -0 /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$PLISTCMD"
> ```

- Enjoy!

Answer (score 16):

The scheme actions aren't in source control so it's better to add a build phase into your app's target. Syncing the versions across all targets can be solved with a simple script that can be modified for every target you want synced:

1. Add "**New Run Script Phase**" in "**Build Phases**" for your app's target

[image]

2. Rename the script to something like "Sync Versions" and drag it above "**Compile Sources**" (NOTE: Xcode has a bug that may prevent the drag-drop to work. If so, you'll need to manually edit the .pbxproj file so the build phase goes in the right spot
3. Paste the following script into the shell:

   ```
   INFOPLIST_MYAPP="${SRCROOT}/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist"
   myAppVersion=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "$INFOPLIST_MYAPP")
   myAppBuild=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_MYAPP")

   INFOPLIST_SHAREEXT="${SRCROOT}/ShareExtension/Info.plist"
   /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $myAppVersion" "$INFOPLIST_SHAREEXT"
   /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $myAppBuild" "$INFOPLIST_SHAREEXT"
   ```

[image]

4. Build your project as you normally and your share extension's version & build will stay in sync with your main target.

Comment: Note that you need to write your own path here: `"${SRCROOT}/MyApp/MyApp-Info.plist"` and here `"${SRCROOT}/ShareExtension/Info.plist"`.

Comment: Not work in Xcode 11 because it moved build number in `Build Settings`

Comment: @NikKov any suggestion on how to get this to work with Xcode 11?

Comment: @RichardWitherspoon check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62213222/5790492

Answer (score 4):

### Xcode 12

I was able to achieve keeping the target extension version and build strings in sync with the main app with the following:

1. Add a `Run Script Phase` above `Compile Sources`
2. Add the following to the content of the newly created Run Script:

```
WIDGET_EXTENSION="${SRCROOT}/MyWidget/Info.plist"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString ${MARKETING_VERSION}" "$WIDGET_EXTENSION"
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion ${CURRENT_PROJECT_VERSION}" "$WIDGET_EXTENSION"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a really sweet version management system that Twitch has shared.

Described in this [blog post](https://blog.twitch.tv/ios-versioning-89e02f0a5146), it is somewhat similar to stk's accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32974655/3728792) but cleaner and also supports the following:

- Ties the build number directly (and reversibly) to the git commit before the build. Go back easily to the exact version built for use with crash report.
- Handles version generation through a target dependency, which is easier to share across multiple targets.
- Uses C Preprocessor on Info.plist functionality built into Xcode build settings to allow the version numbers to be substituted on the fly, with no modification of the Info.plist file.

It is a little more complex to implement, but it's the best solution I've found, particularly if you have extensions or other targets whose versions must be kept in sync.

***Installation Notes:*** Note the blog does a great job of describing the four shell files, but doesn't really give installation or customization instructions. Here's what I did:

1. Create a Versions subdirectory at the top level of your project (where the .xcodeproj lives).
2. Download the four files indicated from the gist link at bottom left of the code samples. Move the four files into your Versions directory.
3. Using terminal, cd to your Versions directory, then execute the cmd: `chmod +x *` to make the shell files executable
4. Now follow the directions in the blog from the start to create your dependency target.
5. You probably should customize the scripts a bit. I altered the naming and refactored to move the 4 tools to a separate tools directory that I share across projects. YMMV.

Comment: For posterity, the blog post link is https://blog.twitch.tv/ios-versioning-89e02f0a5146 and even though it is very xCode-centric, can be adapted to use with Bitrise.io or other CI service.

Answer (score 2):

### Xcode 11+

1) Go to project settings, choose PROJECT (above targets), go to `Build Settings`
2) Press `Add User-Defined Setting` and add `APP_BUILD` and `APP_VERSION`
3) In your targets go to `Info` and replace `Bundle version` to `$(APP_BUILD)` and `Bundle version string` to `$(APP_VERSION)` in all targets and extensions where you need to sync.
4) Woila! You should change bundle versions only in one place - in `Build Settings` of your PROJECT.

Comment: Hi Nik, I use Xcode 11 and have the service extension. in my main app the Bundle Version and Bundle Version String increment according to my svn commit. I don't know in my extension plist how to inherit the the Bundle Version and Bundle Version String from main app. your example above, should I do them in main app or in my extension?

Answer (score 1):

The version of your ProjectTodayExtension.appex have to be the same as your app. example:

Target> General:

Version: 1.0 <- change here
Biuld: 1.0

If the version of your app to get on itunes connect is 2.3, then you must change the version of your TodayExtension to the same version 2.3.

Comment: I know how to solve the error. What I ask is if there is a way to keep in sync Version/Build between targets.

Comment: Look at my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I utilized the excellent answer from stk, but there was a snag that I wanted to mention so others are aware:

Setting the user-defined constants for the primary target (main app executable) resulted in errors when uploading the app to the store. At least in Xcode 13.0, Xcode crashed when it was trying to create a URL parameter to verify the version number with the server. Directly setting the version numbers for the main target fixed the issue.  All the other "sub-targets" work fine using the defined constants.

Answer (score -1):

When trying to validate my archive I got an error message CFBundleShortVersionString missing.
To fix the problem I went into Info.plist in the xml code and added CFBundleShortVersionString
 new version number
This produced in plist format Bundle versions string, short
This solve my problem