# CFBundleShortVersionString Mismatch

Tags: ios, xcode

[image: Photo]

What should I do here? I am trying to submit a new version of app, but I am getting this error when I try to change version number from 1.0 to 1.1 in Xcode.

Comment: May this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30441750/use-same-cfbundleversion-and-cfbundleshortversionstring-in-all-targets

Answer (score 2):

You should also change your `StickerPackExtension.appex` to version `1.1` as indicated.

It can either be changed through the `Xcode` > `General` tab (after selecting the extension target), or edit the extensions `Info.plist` and change the `CFBundleShortVersionString` to reflect the same version number that the main application has.

Comment: I changed version and build number to 1.1 in Info.plist and it says it doesnt match. The older version number was 1.0 and build number was 1

Comment: Try cleaning and then re-building/archiving the project.

Answer (score 0):

This might apply to someone out there.

If you have more than one Target under "Targets" to the left on the Xcode -> General page, you'd need to change the build version for all Targets as well.